# Deleting rows from table on web retrieved from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I am having issue with deleting rows from a database that I echoed onto my website, I have used tick check boxes and when multiples are selected they should be deleted. But it's just NOT HAPPENING! Nothing is getting deleted from the database! please help!

```
<form method="" action="tester.php">
  <?php 

include 'connect_to_mysql.php';
$count=0;
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking ORDER BY ID ASC");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>DEL</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email ID</th>
<th>Phone Number</th>
<th>Collection Address</th>
<th>Collection Date</th>
<th>Collection Time</th>
<th>Make & Model</th>
<th>Message</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
      ?>
           <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete_these[]"                                                                                                                         type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"></td>
   <?php
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['phonenumber'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['collectionaddress'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['collectiondate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['collectiontime'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['makemodel'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['message'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
?> <br>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit"                 id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>

<?php
// Check if delete button active, start this 
if(isset($_GET['delete']))  {

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$id =(int)$_POST['delete_these'][$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM booking WHERE ID='$id'";
print_r($_GET['delete_these[]']);
$sql = "DELETE FROM booking WHERE id IN($ids)";
echo "<br />SQL: $sql<br />";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}


if($result){

}
}
mysql_close();
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you can just `implode()` all the gathered ids from the form and from there build the query.

Sample code:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<table>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete_these[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Selected" />
</form>

<?php
$selected_values = array();
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $selected_values = $_POST['delete_these'];
    $ids = implode(',', $selected_values);
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM booking WHERE id IN($ids)");
    // this becomes -> delete from booking where id in (1, 2, 3, ...)
}
?>
```

and while you still can, use mysqli or PDO, its free anyway

Comment: Thankyou very much @kevinabelita it works perfect! your a lifesaver! which social networking site are you on so o can follow you. thanks

Comment: no need to follow, im always around here anyway, if this helped you you can kindly accept this as an answer and good day